# Canonical form for bilinear function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $V$, $W$ are inner product spaces of the same finite dimension, and that we are given a real-valued $B=B(-,-)$ which is linear in each slot, with the first accepting arguments in $V$ and the second in $W$. Thus, picking a basis for $V$ and a basis for $W$ gives an $n\times n$ matrix. My question is:

Q: Can we pick orthonormal bases of $V$ and $W$ such that the associated matrix of $B$ is diagonal?

The first thing I tried was constructing a symmetric bilinear form $C$ on $V$ by fixing an arbitrary isometry $T: V\rightarrow W$ and defining $C(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(B(x,Ty)+B(y,Tx))$. However, diagonalizing $C$ does not diagonalize $B$. Maybe there's a way to adjust this idea so that it works.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Singular value decomposition seems to be the thing to do here.

Comment: I'm delighted to find I have never encountered this concept before. Can you say anything more about it, and how it bears on the question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Take a basis $B_1$ of  $V$ and a basis $B_2$ of $W$. Let $M$ be the associated matrix of the bilinear form $B$.

Then there are matrices $U,V,\Sigma \in F^{n,n}$ ($F=\mathbb R$ or $F=\mathbb C$) such that $M=U\Sigma V$. $U$ and $V$ are unitary, $\Sigma$ is diagonal. You can now use the matrices $U$ and $V$ to transform the original bases of $V$ and $W$ to bases such that the associated matrix of $B$ is diagonal.

Comment: Based on a look at the Wikipedia page, I think this is exactly the concept I was looking for. I now wish I had asked earlier and not spent so much time trying to (unsuccessfully) rediscover it!